# how to perform classification using function train in caret in R

Tags: r, classification, prediction

I have 20 classes, and I want to classify and predict class label:

```
library("caret")
model=train(x=df_train,y=train_class, method="nnet")
pred=predict(model,df_test)
```

The output of `pred` is real number (it performs regression), How can I ask to return me prediction of class labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be better suited to stackoverflow, though you have not given a reproducible example.

The following predicts the species class label for the *iris* dataset, adapting the example from `?train`

```
library(caret)
library(MASS)
data(iris)
set.seed(1)
TestRows     <- c(sample(50,15), sample(50,15)+50, sample(50,15)+100)
TrainData    <- iris[-TestRows,1:4]
TrainClasses <- iris[-TestRows,5]
TestData     <- iris[TestRows,1:4]
TestClasses  <- iris[TestRows,5]
nnetFit <- train(x=TrainData, y=TrainClasses,
                 method = "nnet",
                 preProcess = "range", 
                 tuneLength = 2,
                 trace = FALSE,
                 maxit = 100)
```

and gives the following result for the training set:

```
> table(TrainClasses, predict(nnetFit)) 

TrainClasses setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         35          0         0
  versicolor      0         34         1
  virginica       0          1        34
```

and for the test set

```
> table(TestClasses,  predict(nnetFit,TestData))  

TestClasses  setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         15          0         0
  versicolor      0         15         0
  virginica       0          3        12
```

which I find surprisingly accurate for the *versicolor/virginica* distinction

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But, when I apply to my data `predict(nnetFit,TestData)[1]` is `0.9923`. It returns regression prediction of my data. I think the problem comes from `levels` of data. `levels(iris)` shows the three classes but `levels(myData)` is `Null`. Do this `levels` is problem? how to fix this?

Comment: No - this works without levels in the input data.    But without seeing your data, it is difficult to say much more.  What type of data is your  `train_class`